# What type is bit shift operator output?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have the following code

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
          //find sign of 32 bit integer
    int a=0x6348987C;
    a=a>>31;
    int one=a&1;
    if( one==0 )
    {
     System.out.println("Positive"); 
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println("Negative");  
    }

  }
```

If I change the comparison line with `if( a&1 ==0 )` the compilation fails with operator & cannot be applied to int,boolean, mking me wonder what is the resulting type of the shift operator.

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` equality operator precedes the bitwise AND operator in terms of operator precedence (see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). You should place parentheses to make the latter precede:

```
if ((a & 1) == 0) {
```

Note that the type of the result of `a & 1` is the same type of `one` in the original code (`int`).

Comment: Hmm..Thanks for pointing it out, operator precedence, the error made no sense to me.